# java- finding a subset sum using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, subset

The goal of the program is to see if one of the inputs in the array can be a sum of any combination of the other inputs. I understand the theory behind it and have come up with how I would solve it but I'm not sure how to implement it. I decided to sort the array from least to greatest and then i figured I would go from comparing pairs of numbers to the following inputs and then using 3 inputs, and then 4, etc etc. but I have no idea how I would use recursion to solve this. Some direction would be extremely helpful, not looking for a full answer thanks!

Comment: This is the knapsack problem, and you solve it recursively using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Let me see..

You need a target sum, so thats one of the arguements.

You need a sum so far, so thats another.

```
Boolean IsSubsetSum(int[] sorted array, int Target,int maxIndex , int SumSoFar = 0);
```

This sounds like a good place to start.

If SumSoFar == Target

return true

else if maxIndex == 0

return false

else

Add array[maxIndex] to the sum and call recusively, with appropriate arguments..

This step would loop over 0..maxIndex, so not very efficient, but will do for a start. You need to calculate the return values from the return values of the recusive calls, you can exit early if you find true.